# hiding deployed webpartpage from topnavigation menu

Tags: web-part-page, pages

I have created several webpartpages, in the module xml file I set the page to be deployed to the Pages library.

When I'm browsing the site I can see that the names of my webpartpages are shown in the 
TopNavigation Menu.

How can I set that those names won't be shown in the menu ? (programmatically)

TIA
Ronen

Answer (score 0):

I believe several clarifications are needed - You say "Web part pages" and than "Pages" library (Publishing site usually)  - even if you can do that is not really recomanded! You need to deploy Publishing Pages based on Layouts usually.

Now - the top navigation is configurable via the Site Settings > Top-link bar or Quick Launch (for left navigation), but i believe you have a Publishing Site, which is configured via Site Settings > Navigation, and there you should un-check the "Pages" checkbox in the Global Navigation.

Comment: I'll try to clarify

I created a "Web Part Page" from within VS2012, so when I deploy the solution I set the location which this "Web Part Page" will reside. 
In Elemens.xml I did : <Module Name="HRPages" Url="Pages">
So after deploy my "Web Part Page" copied to Pages library.

Maybe I should copy those "Web Part Pages" to a different location so they won't be shown in the TopNavigation ?

Also as you stated the site setting - navigation is a powerful option if there is no solution to set it programmatically

Comment: just to mention even if I hide the pages I don't want to see in the Site Setting-navigation , after deployed they showing again.... 
That's why I wanted to know if I can set a hide property for them already in the deploy process